# Angular resolver with generic base class used in multiple modules

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a resolver like this

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CandidateResolver implements Resolve<Observable<Candidate>> {
    constructor(private service: CandidateService) {
    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Candidate> {
        return this.service.getCandidate(route.params.candidateId);
    }
}
```

Then I have 2 subclasses of CandidateService

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
    export class AgencyOwnerCandidateService extends CandidateService

 @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
    export class RecruiterCandidateService extends CandidateService
```

Im registering the service like this in 2 modules, `AgencyOwnerModule` and `RecruiterModule` respectively.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':orgId/agency-owner/candidates/:candidateId',
        component: AgencyOwnerCandidateComponent,
        resolve: {
            candidate: CandidateResolver
        }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AgencyOwnerCandidateComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: CandidateService,
            useClass: AgencyOwnerCandidateService
        }
    ]
})
export class AgencyOwnerCandidatesModule {
}
```

When I actually run the route, it's getting the wrong concrete type.  I obviously see why, as the modules are being loaded based on token names across all modules.

Is there any way control which concrete type is being loaded with DI as I'm expecting?